# Why is splitting the same video a second time is faster?

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I am splitting a video using `ffmpeg` without renencoding. On first attempt, it takes a minute or two depending on file size. Though, if I split the same file again, even if I change the end time, the file is split within just a few seconds. It does not even take 10 seconds. Why does this happen?

Thank you.

Comment: It might be helpful if you can include the exact commands you used both times

Comment: without more information, I would say the file is now cached by the operating system, so the time reading it is greatly reduced.

Comment: It probably did some encoding the first time, but saw that it already had that encoding the second time, so it could skip a step that normally takes a long time. Usually if you set the encoding options identical to what the file already is, it will skip it, even the first time.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. Here is the command I use for cutting all videos. `ffmpeg.exe -ss start-time -to end-time -i video-path -c copy cut-path -y`

Comment: @YisroelTech I provided the command in the comment above this.

Comment: Edit your question to make it more clear. When you are asked to provide more info, add that requested info to the question so that it becomes a better question. Good questions are more likely to get good answers.